# python - does a function in the right side of a conditional `and` run when the left side fails?

Tags: python, operator-precedence

consider this:

```
valid = data and func(data)
```

In the cases where `data` will be `False`, will python still run the function on the right side of the `and` condition? (it will error if run, so I'm trying to figure out if I need to check `data` within `func` or is the above code fine as is)

Comment: No. This is called short-circuiting.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thank you. I was not familiar with the name `short-circuit` so I couldn't have found the duplicate question on my own

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's easy to try:

```
>>> 0 and False
0
```

so the answer is: python will not run `func(data)` if `data` is `False`.